# What is the default behavior of Cache-Control

Tags: performance, http, nginx, cache-control, expires

If no `private` nor `public` were defined in the cache-control, e.g.

```
 Cache-Control: max-age=31461276
```

What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem it tells browser that the cache expires after 1 year, 31461276 seconds means 1 year.

More details in this post: [EXPIRES VS. MAX-AGE](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2007/05/15/expires_max-age)

Comment: I know what is expires and max-age, but just don't know what are the different if I missed the `public`

Comment: @Yoga I guess it behaves as public unless you have HTTP authentication.

Comment: This made sense.

Answer (score 12):

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3:

```
The max-age directive on a response implies that the response is cacheable
(i.e., "public") unless some other, more restrictive cache directive is 
also present.
```

It's conceivable (likely?) that there are proxies in the wild which break this but since the only failure mode could be treating a public resource as private the consequences should be minimal beyond a modest performance hit. You'll have far more problems with proxies which do things like cache resources far beyond your specified `max-age`.